# i am not able to include js file because of MIME(text/html) in node js

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am trying to build my own webrtc platform but because of this error i am not able to include peer.js file into my code.
The script from “http://localhost:3000/peer.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Here is the code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
    const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <script src="peer.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #video-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    }
    
    video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your Node.js code, that makes the `http://localhost:3000/peer.js` accessible, look like? And also: You can also force the browser to treat it like the correct mime type, using `<script src="peer.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

give `peer.js` a proper path only providing name will include the file which is present in same directory.